# jquery escaping quotes to insert element with classes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, escaping

I'm using React, Bootstrap, and jQuery to insert an alert but don't know how to escape it correctly in to include the appropriate attributes for my div element

```
   $(submitInput).after("<div className=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">Wrong Phone Format</div>");
```

Comment: I would urge you to not use jQuery in your React-project, unless you are not capable of solving some problems without it. I find that jQuery is sometimes useful for certain animations, which can be very hard to do with just HTML/CSS, albeit not impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quote at first and at the end :

```
 $(submitInput).after('<div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Wrong Phone Format</div>');
 //-------------------^-------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```